# Dividing $18$ students into $3$ groups of $6$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there of dividing $18$ students into $3$ groups of $6$?

The person who marked my assignment said that it was

$$\frac{18!}{(6!)^3}$$ but I thought it was $$\frac{18!}{(6!)^3(3!)}$$ because you could switch all $3$ partitions around and still have the same way of dividing them.

Comment: You are right. Consider a much simpler case of dividing two students into two groups of one, the number of possibility is obviously $1$, $\frac{2!}{1!\times 1!}\neq 1$ but $\frac{2!}{2!\times 1!\times 1!}\neq 1$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I think you made a small typo, the second $\neq$ should be an $=$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the ordering of the groups does not matter. There are $\binom{18}{6}$ ways to choose students for the first group, then $\binom{12}{6}$ for the second group (there are $18-6=12$ students left, and $\binom{6}{6}$ for the last group. We now need to divide by $3!$ because the order of the $3$ groups does not matter.

Hence, the answer is

$$\frac{1}{3!} \left( \binom{18}{6} \cdot \binom{12}{6} \cdot \binom{6}{6} \right) = \frac{18! \cdot12! \cdot 6!}{12! \cdot 6! \cdot 0! \cdot (6!)^3 \cdot3} = \frac{18!}{(6!)^3 \cdot 3!},$$

i.e. your answer.

If the order of the groups did matter, you wouldn't divide by $3!$, getting the teachers answer (e.g. if you wanted to give the groups distinct labels.)

Here, $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, which is equal to the number of ways to choose $k$ things out of a collection of $n$ things, where order does not matter, with

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

The assignment is not clear, because we don't know whether the groups are distinguishable. As an example, consider the following similarly unclear problem: how many ways are there to pair up $4$ students $A,B,C,D$?

Distinguishable pairs example: "How many ways are there to put $4$ students $A,B,C,D$ into two groups $X,Y$ such that each group contains $2$ students?

Indistinguishable pairs example: "How many ways are there for $A,B,C,D$ to play a doubles tennis match (where two players play against two others)?